# Clean url string with backslashes and brackets using php so it is a useable url

Tags: php

I'm returning an array from gravity forms and the value contains a url, but for some reason it's added brackets, quote marks, and backslashes!?

I've looked at `preg_replace()` but seems a little long winded.

And I've look `stripslashes()` but it removes all the slashes.

My question is there a simple function solution that makes this string value into a usuable url which I can echo out in my page?

Here is my string value below in its entirety...

```
["http:\/\/joshbakerson.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/gravity_forms\/1-61ecbcd1ce76f3a9c22cc8ee3d541e5b\/2017\/01\/The-Funniest-moment-ever-when-bear-starts-then-bottles-it.mp4"]
```

I simply want to convert the string above to this...

http://joshbakerson.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-61ecbcd1ce76f3a9c22cc8ee3d541e5b/2017/01/The-Funniest-moment-ever-when-bear-starts-then-bottles-it.mp4

Any advice on what function I should use would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stripslashes()` should work for you, as it only removes the `\` characters:

```
$x = '["http:\/\/joshbakerson.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/gravity_forms\/1-61ecbcd1ce76f3a9c22cc8ee3d541e5b\/2017\/01\/The-Funniest-moment-ever-when-bear-starts-then-bottles-it.mp4"]';

$output =  stripslashes($x);
```

you can then use `str_replace()` to remove the `[`, `]`, and `"` characters:

```
$output = str_replace('[','', $output);
$output = str_replace(']','', $output);
$output = str_replace('"','', $output);

echo $output;
//   http://joshbakerson.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-61ecbcd1ce76f3a9c22cc8ee3d541e5b/2017/01/The-Funniest-moment-ever-when-bear-starts-then-bottles-it.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks dude, so I used your method just combined the string replace into an array to make it shorter... `str_replace(array('[','"',']'), '', stripslashes($string]))` much appreciated thanks for the tip

Comment: oh great, glad it worked for you.  And I didn't realize that you could pass an array to `str_replace()`.  That's good to know.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$string = 'http:\/\/joshbakerson.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/gravity_forms\/1-61ecbcd1ce76f3a9c22cc8ee3d541e5b\/2017\/01\/The-Funniest-moment-ever-when-bear-starts-then-bottles-it.mp4';
$data = str_replace('\/','\\',$string);
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment bro but I managed to get the result using this... `str_replace(array('[','"',']'), '', stripslashes($string))`

Comment: I did not notice the brackets ... in fact is a better way.

Comment: Thanks anyway man.. So odd why brackets and quotes exist as a value anyway... :-/